# Cant remove tr elements inside of table with index

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a table, where I input elements from object.
There are limited number of elements, that can be rendered on the page. So in order to see more, you will click on next/ previous, to see other "page".

The problem is, that I want to remove the indexes, that are not to be displayed.

The logic on the bottom is I set min and max index and to see different page, I will increment these numbers by 10 ( to get 10 results on the page) but when I click on next button, I want to remove 0 - 10 and have only 10 - 20, but table.deleteRow(index) does nothing. (but table.deteteRow(1) does work)

```
function fill(){
        prices.forEach((element,index) =>{
            const table = document.querySelector("table");
            const tr = document.createElement("tr");
            tableItems.appendChild(tr);
            
           
            if(index >= min && index < max){
                
                const type = document.createElement("td");
                const name = document.createElement("td");
                const hours = document.createElement("td");
                const photos = document.createElement("td");
                const place = document.createElement("td");
                const price = document.createElement("td");

                type.innerHTML = element.type;
                name.innerHTML = element.name;
                hours.innerHTML = element.hours;
                photos.innerHTML = element.photos;
                place.innerHTML = element.place;
                price.innerHTML = element.price;

                tr.appendChild(type);
                tr.appendChild(name);
                tr.appendChild(hours);
                tr.appendChild(photos);
                tr.appendChild(place);
                tr.appendChild(price);
            }

            if(index > max){
                table.deleteRow(index);
            }
    
            //
        });
    }


    buttonRight.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        min = max;
        max = max + 10;

        fill();
    });
    buttonLeft.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        max = min;
        min = min -10;

        fill();
    });
```

Comment: Use removeChild()

Comment: I have a bigger problems when using removeChild. It always throws errors, so I wanted to use deleteRow() instead

Comment: Is it really necessary to do dom manipulation here? Seems this could be achieved with css and a few classes (assigned/removed via javascript).

Comment: Well I thought of it, that I would assign the ones that are to be displayed with active class and the others would be display:none, but I have not come across removing elements with JS and I took it as a practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always you should delete rows with index 0-9 and you shouldn't change index number, because always you have 10 rows in your table.
It seems that when you click Next button, simple way is to remove all tr from table before calling of the fill function.